# After Logout user can still access protected page

Tags: php, html, mysql

I added a session & used this code to prevent user from accessing a page after logout but i can't do so. User can still access the previous page.Here is the code

login code is

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="alogin.php" onsubmit="return(validate());">
  <p align="center"><font style="Arial" size="+1" color="#000000">Username : 
    <label for="name"></label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
  </p>
  <br />
  <br />
  <p align="center">Password : 
    <label for="pass"></label>
    <input type="password" name="pass" id="pass" /></font>
  </p>
  <p align="center">
    <br />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Login" />
  </p>
</form>
```

in each protected page i used this

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['name'])) {
  header("location:login.html");
} else {
}
?>
```

while logout.php contains

```
 <?php
session_start();
$_SESSION=array();
setcookie(session_name(),"",time()-3600);
session_destroy();
header("Location: login.html?id=You are successfully logged out");
?>
```

Comment: What type are the "Protected pages" php, html ?

Comment: You need to add `session_start();` where you state `"in each protected page i used this"` as your first line under `<?php`.

Comment: @fred sorry i forget to mentioned i used session_start(); in every page. question edited

Comment: If the user is just hitting the back button, could this be a browser cache problem?

Comment: @bksi if you have a look at protected pages you can guess it's PHP for sure bro

Comment: I mean what extension they have?

Comment: @graham i don't think so. A Couple of days ago the same coding was working. i added couple of things & it stopped working. i tried to get to issue but unable :(

Comment: Try adding a `session_destroy();` in each protected page, see what that gives.

Comment: @bksi .php is the extension bro

Comment: Then the problem is the cache. As @Ed Heal said below just make sure there are no further iteractions.

Comment: @bksi bro things were working and redireting user to particular page (login.html) as directed don't know what happened lately :/

Comment: @CodingNoob Seems like you're not defining a session name in `setcookie(session_name(),"",time()-3600);`, might be it. As set in `if(!isset($_SESSION['name']))`. Try `setcookie(session_name(),"name",time()-3600);`, or something to that affect.

Comment: Can you post the code you changed?

Comment: @fred on adding session_destroy(); it says "Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\cms\viewall.php:327) in C:\xampp\htdocs\cms\viewall.php on line 328

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\cms\viewall.php:327) in C:\xampp\htdocs\cms\viewall.php on line 332"

Comment: @graham there were a lot of changes. adding php forms, java script i am afraid i can't put in 18 pages in here :/

Comment: @fred added your suggested change no effect :/

Comment: @CodingNoob most bizarre. (baffled). Any luck with the others' answers/suggestions?

Comment: @CodingNoob This doesn't make sense and is most bizarre. The only other thing that comes to mind is that you're defining a session name in `$_SESSION['name']` called `"name"`, yet you're not defining it elsewhere.

Comment: Can you please confirm, clicking the back button displays the page as a logged in used would see it, now refresh the page, what do you see? If you're not redirected, your php is messed up. If it does redirect you, your browser is cacheing the page, and you'll have to set an expiration header to force the browser to reload the page.

Comment: @graham i can see page as a logged in user.

Comment: @fred nope everything is failed :(. and regarding "name" i used this field for user to sign in mean $_POST html form you can see it in first coding

Comment: After you've refreshed the page? That means the php session is not being unset/destroyed. By any chance, did you make any changes to your logout file? `$_SESSION=array();` looks suspicious to me, try commenting it out

Comment: @graham did it but no :'( not working :/

Comment: someone told me you have to write session_start(); thingy at the top of your page. i did this & now whenever i click on that particular page it simply redirects me to login.html :/

Comment: k let me explain what i am doing it might help you guzy to understand issue. user is signing in using a html form which redirects you to admin panel --> username field is known as "name" i am setting that name to session & all other things you can see in my code above

Comment: @CodingNoob Is your form by any chance a `.php` or `.html` file? This could make a huge difference.

Comment: @fred form is .html protected pages are php & logout is php too

Comment: @CodingNoob what I meant was, does your form have an `.html` extension or `.php`?

Comment: @fred dear that's what i mentioned above. form has extension ".html"

Comment: @CodingNoob I think that's the `root` of your problem.

Comment: @fred :O how. can you please elaborate it & solution too. i am facing this issue from 3 days & i always keep doing other things cause i was unable to deal with it

Comment: @CodingNoob Since your form is plain HTML, of course it will remain in cache memory. If it were a PHP based/name file with the sessions codes etc. inside it, will look for a session/cookie. If not found, then it should theoretically stop any further action. I can post something to show you, but not as an answer, but a `suggestive` (answer) in order to show you what I use and works rather well.

Comment: @fred sure i will wait & your final answer is coding is all right its the cache?

Comment: @CodingNoob Cache could play a role in all of this, however starting off with plain HTML and finishing off in PHP, to me does not make for a good recipe. ;-)

Comment: @fred hmmmm i will work on it too. but will be looking for a solution to current situation too.

Comment: @CodingNoob I posted a `suggestive` answer below, easier to show as an answer, then in the `comments` box.

Comment: session_start should be set at the very begin of the file, because if server send some char (some error message for example, BOM chars, etc)  to the browser, session_start couldn't apply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

created a file named as session.php

```
   <?php
                    ob_start();    
                    session_start();
                    // just call this file session.php and share it in all your file, which you want to protect with session,
    ?>
```

than we need to include the file in every page we want protected like this way

```
<?php
include 'session.php';
var_dump($_SESSION);

if(isset($_SESSION) ){
        if(!$_SESSION['name']=='admin'){
                header("Location:login.html?id=access_forbidde");
        }
}else{
header("Location:viewall.php?id=access_forbidde");
}
```

in else you have to name each page separetly in that particular page.

& logout contains

```
<?php
include 'session.php';
$_SESSION=array();
setcookie(session_name(),"",time()-3600);
session_destroy();
header("Location: login.html?id=logout_successful");
?>
```

thanks to PHP_Noob for his help. & i made it after a week

Answer (score 5):

When the user issues "back" to its browser, the browser can decide to load the page from it's cache. the user won't be able to do what a logged in user can do because the session has been destroyed and is invalid.

A possible workaround would be to include an AJAX-request on those sensible pages that checks if the user is still logged in. If yes, display the sensitive elements (or get them via ajax) and if not (the user is logged out) display a warning or forward him to a login-page (via js).

Comment: i am confused. can you explain it a bit please. couple of days ago things were working and redirecting to login page as directed in session code. don't know what happened after adding some more code.

Comment: It's, about settings. You can set headers, with expire page, so the browser can refresh the page via request instead its cache.

Comment: the page can get saved onto the disk of the user, and if the user hit's back the browser will not download the page from your site but from the hard disk, at the moment the page was being saved the user was logged in so that page is shown.

Comment: @bksi how. sorry i am totally noob :/

Comment: @flesh hmm but i think it's not the case. may be i am wrong cause things were working

Comment: @CodingNoob Can you indicate in the question what code you added which made it stop working?

Comment: @pal4life sorry dear i don't think so that i can add some javascripts a lot of query's & some php coding too. but i am sure i did not edited logout file & yes i made some changes in session things which i don't remember don't i have a copy either :/

Answer (score 2):

It is called a cache. Therefore there is not a request made to the server.

Just ensure no further interaction is possible.

Comment: couple of days ago things were working and redirecting to login page as directed in session code. don't know what happened after adding some more code.

Comment: @CodingNoob - Mystic Meg has gone to bed! - So cannot tell you why adding that extra code has effected the cache behaviour. Maybe you are not using 'POST' anymore.

Comment: o.O that's the point. i think i did this. let me search through my pages again

Answer (score 1):

after `header("location:login.html");` You might want to also do `die();` to prevent the logged-in html from being outputted too.

Answer (score 0):

***PLEASE NOTE***: This is only a "suggestive" answer.

**This is what I use and works rather well.**

In your form, which must have the `.php` file extension, use something to the affect of:

```
session_start();
$firstname = $_SESSION['unique_session_name'];
// yours being $name

// some code

$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
```

**Then, in your protected pages:**

```
session_start();
$_SESSION["unique_session_name"] = $_POST["firstname"];

   if (isset($_SESSION['unique_session_name'])) {

// some code

}
```

Comment: i tried it. Else part is working that mean session is not getting set form anywhere. am i right? i tried this     "<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION["unique_session_name"] = $_POST["firstname"];

   if (isset($_SESSION['unique_session_name'])) 
   {
header("location:login.html");
}
else
{
 header("location:create_question.php");
}?>" yes i applied this in vice versa condition just for checking and if is not working at all :/

Comment: @CodingNoob Did you change your form to reflect `firstname` instead of just `name`?

Answer (score 0):

Going by the logic you mentioned, seems like an issue with how you are checking for session. Does not work if you are doing a **session_start();** on your protected pages on top and then checking for session.

Try this to check for session

```
if(session_id() == '') {
    // session isn't started
 session_start();
}
else
{
 header("location:login.html");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is sort of a stab in the dark here as others have mentioned the cache issue. I had a similar problem not too long ago I believe I solved it by manually un-setting the session variable I was checking. I'm not sure this will help but it seemed to work for me.

```
session_unset();
unset($_SESSION['name']);
```

It was a case of just trying everything possible.

Comment: dude it's still not working. I am going crazy with this stuff now :@. i think i need to re-write all the code. can someone help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

I create a cookie called 'session-cookie' and set it's value to true when the user successfully logs in.

When a user logs out, I set the 'session-cookie' to empty.

Then add the following in Javascript,

```
<script>
if( document.cookie.indexOf("session-cookie") < 0 ) {
 location.replace('http://[any url]/'); 
}
</script>
```

They'll be able to hit the back button and view the cached page, but it will quickly redirect and overwrite the current page in history.